# Some questions about Regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I would like to do some text conversion, such as reading in from a text file:

```
CONTENTS
1. INTRODUCTION
1.1 The Linear Programming Problem 2
1.2 Examples of Linear Problems 7
```

and writing to another text file:

```
("CONTENTS" "#") 
("1. INTRODUCTION" "#") 
("1.1 The Linear Programming Problem 2" "#11")  
("1.2 Examples of Linear Problems 7" "#16")
```

The current Python code I use for such conversion is:

```
infile = open(infilename)
outfile = open(outfilename, "w")

pat = re.compile('^(.+?(\d+)) *$',re.M)
def zaa(mat):
    return '("%s" "#%s")' % (mat.group(1),str(int(mat.group(2))+9))

outfile.write('(bookmarks \n')
for line in infile:
    outfile.write(pat.sub(zaa,line))
outfile.write(')')
```

1. It will convert the original text to

   ```
   CONTENTS
   1. INTRODUCTION
   ("1.1 The Linear Programming Problem 2" "#11")
   ("1.2 Examples of Linear Problems 7" "#16")
   ```

   The last two lines are correct, but
   the first two lines are not. So I
   was wondering how to accommodate the
   first two lines, by modifying the
   current code, or using some
   different code?
2. The code was not written by me, but
   I would like to understand the usage
   of `re.sub()` here. As I found from
   a Python website,

   > re.sub(regex, replacement, subject)
   >   performs a search-and-replace across
   >   subject, replacing all matches of
   >   regex in subject with replacement. The
   >   result is returned by the sub()
   >   function. The subject string you pass
   >   is not modified.

   But in my code, its usage is
   `pat.sub(zaa,line)', which seems to
   me not consistent to the quoted
   description. So I was wondering how
   to understand the usage in my code?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this the real code? You are adding 11, but 2+11 = 13 not 11.

Comment: @Mikel: Thanks for pointing it out. My typo. Just corrected.

Comment: I got confused about the `re.sub()` thing too. Turns out there are _two_ sub functions: `re.sub(pattern, repl, string[, count])` and another to be used with a compiled regex object: `RegexObject.sub(repl, string[, count=0])`. This function is using the latter syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tested script generates the desired output:

```py
import re
infilename = "infile.txt"
outfilename = "outfile.txt"

infile = open(infilename)
outfile = open(outfilename, "w")

pat = re.compile('^(.+?(\d*)) *$',re.M)
def zaa(mat):
    if mat.group(2):
        return '("%s" "#%s")' % (mat.group(1),str(int(mat.group(2))+9))
    else:
        return '("%s" "#")' % (mat.group(1))

outfile.write('(bookmarks \n')
for line in infile:
    outfile.write(pat.sub(zaa,line))
outfile.write(')')
```

Comment: Thanks! Work like a charm! I was wondering ".+" means repeating a character one or more time, or a sequence of one or more characters which are not necessarily the same? If one of the two is what it means, what is the regex to mean the other?

Comment: `.+` means one or more (possibly different) characters.  `(.)\1+` means at least two of the same character.

Comment: The dot means match any one character (except a newline - unless the 's' modifier is set - in which case the dot matches any char including a newline). The plus is a quantifier added to any token which means _one or more_ of the preceding token. The star is similar but it means _zero or more_ of the preceding token.

Answer (score 3):

With your regex you are searching for a line that ends with a number (and maybe trailing whitespace). You could make the number optional: `^(.+?(\d+)?) *$` and make sure your group 2 reference inside `zaa` can handle an empty string.

```
def zaa(mat):
    return '("%s" "#%s")' % (mat.group(1), (str(int(mat.group(2))+9) if mat.group(2) else "") )
```

With this, you should get "#" when `mat.group(2)` is empty, and what your currently get, when it's not empty.

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering how to make sure my group 2 reference inside zaa can handle an empty string?

Comment: @Tim, I've edited my answer to make it a little more clear. My copy of `zaa` should gracefully handle `map.group(2)` being empty.

Comment: Thanks! I got a "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" at the "?".

Comment: D'oh. Ok, this one compiles now :)

Answer (score 1):

> But in my code, its usage is `pat.sub(zaa,line)`, which seems to me not consistent to the quoted description.

The difference is in the `sub` call; the documentation you quote is to the `re.sub` *function*, but what is being used here is the `sub` *method* of a compiled [regular expression object](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-objects). The initial pattern argument in `re.sub()` is replaced with the regular expression object to which the `sub` method is bound. So in other words,

```
pat.sub(zaa, line)
```

is equivalent to

```
re.sub(pat, zaa, line)
```

Terrible variable names by the way.

Comment: Thanks! Is there description about the sub method for a regex object on Python official website?